# Java Libgdx/OpenGL, reason why sprite isn't changing color/drawing

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx, shader

Insanely new to OpenGL, though I've used Libgdx for a bit.

I'm implementing some code from this tutorial for [distance field fonts](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Distance-field-fonts).

the vert and frag files are almost the same as the author of the tutorial, though I'm trying to change the color and alpha through java code.

Here's how I'm implementing the shader program

```
    ShaderProgram shaderProgram = ShaderProgram(Gdx.files.internal("Fonts/Shader/font.vert"), Gdx.files.internal("Fonts/Shader/font.frag"));
    AssetLibrary.fontShader.pedantic = false;
    AssetLibrary.fontShader.setUniformf("custom_color", 1, 0, 0, 1);

    batch.setShader(AssetLibrary.fontShader);
    font.draw(batch, layout, pos.x, pos.y);
    batch.setShader(null);
```

And here's my fragment file.

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

uniform sampler2D u_texture;
uniform vec4 custom_color;

varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;

const float smoothing = 1.0/16.0;

void main() {
    float distance = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoord).a;
    float alpha = smoothstep(0.5 - smoothing, 0.5 + smoothing, distance);

    gl_FragColor = vec4(custom_color.rgb, custom_color.a * alpha);
}
```

So I figured that:

```
AssetLibrary.fontShader.setAttributef("custom_color", 1, 0, 0, 1);
```

was going to allow me to set the color of the pixels from Java, but all it's seemingly doing is making my sprite disappear. I also verified that the custom_color.r and custom_color.a are populated using:

```
AssetLibrary.fontShader.getUniformSize("custom_color.r");
AssetLibrary.fontShader.getUniformSize("custom_color.a");
```

and they are.

Now I'm not entirely new to programming, but I'm having a hard time figuring out what the problem is. Nothing is showing on screen. Though, if I go in the frag file and manually set:

```
gl_FragColor = vec4(1, 0, 0, 1 * alpha);
```

it works perfectly, but I need to be able to set the color outside of the shader files. What am I possibly missing here?

Comment: Welp, 2 minutes after I spent a bunch of time formatting this question I figured out the answer. One should set the uniform or attribute after setting the shader to the batch.

Comment: I don't want to necessarily delete this post as someone might find it useful. Advice on what I should do with it?